# Using multiple cores with "blackbox" function

Tags: python, multiprocessing, scikit-learn

Let's say that I have a "blackbox" function with a setup looking like this:

```
def bb_func():
    #Does lots of stuff
    #Including lots of scikit-learn stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bb_func()
```

`bb_func()` is notably CPU intensive and would greatly benefit from using multiple cores. Edit: I only need to run `bb_func()` **once**.

Since I am using `scikit-learn`, I would like to know if there's something available (not necessarily inside the package) to do this.

Comment: Unless you're contemplating running `bb_func` multiple times, any "using multiple cores" would have to be part of the internals of `bb_func`, which you probably can't change, if you're treating it as a black box.

Comment: That's what I thought. The problem is that the most demanding lines (inside the blackbox) are not "splitable"... unless I plan to dig into the packages!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to run a black-box multiple times is to use a worker `Pool` with parallel `map` functions.  There are several python packages that have `map` functions.  `multiprocessing` is one of the most popular, and is built into the python standard library.  I use a package called `pathos`, which builds on the `multiprocessing` interface, and extends it to provide parallel maps over socket connections. `pathos` also provides a much more robust parallel `map` (which I'll discuss below).  Here we see several parallel maps, with different flavors (blocking, asynchronous, and iterative).

```
>>> def bb_func(id):
...   import random
...   import time
...   n = random.random()
...   time.sleep(n)
...   return int(10*n)
... 
>>> import pathos
>>> 
>>> thpool = pathos.multiprocessing.ThreadingPool()
>>> mppool = pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool()
>>> pppool = pathos.pp.ParallelPythonPool()
>>> 
>>> # blocking map using multiple processes
>>> mppool.map(bb_func, range(10))
[4, 5, 8, 7, 4, 2, 0, 0, 5, 3]
>>>
>>> # iterative map using multiple threads
>>> res = thpool.imap(bb_func, range(10))
>>> res.next()
8
>>> res.next()
4
>>> list(res)
[8, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1]
>>>
>>> # asynchronous map able to work across sockets
>>> res = pppool.amap(bb_func, range(10))
>>> res.ready()
True
>>> res.get()
[1, 2, 8, 9, 6, 7, 0, 5, 8, 9]
```

With `pathos`, these maps can also be arranged to provide hierarchical parallelism.  Here we launch 5 multiprocessing maps in asynchronous parallel,
where each multiprocessing map is calling `bb_func` on 10 items.

```
>>> res = thpool.amap(mppool.map, [bb_func]*5, [range(10)]*5)
>>> res.get()
[[7, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 2, 6, 0, 2], [9, 5, 1, 6, 9, 0, 5, 3, 4, 5], [4, 7, 2, 7, 3, 5, 8, 3, 3, 9], [4, 8, 8, 8, 3, 5, 0, 6, 1, 0], [8, 0, 6, 7, 7, 4, 1, 6, 2, 7]]
```

`pathos` also provides the ability to make `ssh tunnel` connections, so if your socket connections need to be secure, you can establish a `ssh tunnel` and make sure the `map` sends the calls across the tunneled socket.  Also, there's a sister package called `pyina` that provides a similar interface for `map` functions using `MPI` as a backend.  I'll leave you to look at that, if you want to work with `MPI` and compute cluster schedulers instead of (or in harmony with) `pathos`. `pyina` uses `mpi4py` under the covers, and provides a more intuitive high-level interface for executing parallel batch calls that leverage `MPI`.

There will be **two critical issues** for your `bb_func`.  First, `bb_func` will need to be serializable.  The `pathos` package (and `pyina`) use the `dill` serializer, because `dill` can serialize most python objects.  If you are importing `bb_func` instead of defining it yourself in the same file (or the interpreter), then it is much more likely to be serializable.  Second, `scikit-learn` can use a lot of memory, so running several `scikit-learn` calls in parallel often can eat up all your memory.  As to how to work around this memory limitation… you'll need to try to be smart about how you are coding, and possibly use tricks like working with memory mapped files, or disposing of large datasets (to files or garbage collection) immediately after they have been used.

Get `pathos` (and `pyina` and `dill`) here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

**EDIT**: I see from your edit that you are only running `bb_func` once, and it's a black-box.  So the answer in that case is easy… "Nope, sorry.  You're stuck unless you want to dig into the black-box."

Comment: That's a great answer, but I do not need to run `bb_func()` multiple times. I only need to run it once, and that seems to be my problem when trying to use existing multiprocessing packages/concepts.